# MVC2 What is the best way to page a table

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

What is the correct way to implement paging on a table with MVC2? Is it possible to do this without reposting the whole form?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how do you wish to implement paging. If you wish to implement server side paging, telerik components are great way to go ahead. There is a free open source version available if that suits your product. Here you can check out and download it

http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc/grid.aspx

If you wish to implement client side paging, nothing beats jquery plugins available. You can see a list of paging plugins at:

http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/pager

I hope this helps, Thanks

Comment: +1 for mentioning jQuery plugins. Note that won't work well for large datasets since it would require the entire page to download in the page, which may take long. Then again, paging through a very large dataset is probably a bad idea anyway.

Comment: exactly. Thanks for mentioning that :)

Answer (score 1):

You may take a look at [MvcContrib Grid](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Grid&ProjectName=mvccontrib) which has paging functionality built-in.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using jQuery/AJAX to update the table without a full refresh.

The new jQuery template library MS contributed canhelp with recreating the table from a template for rows.

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquerytemplate